# Installing grub on new disk

Tags: grub2

I read that installing grub on a new disk should be as simple as :
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb (sdb being my "new" disk)
sudo update-grub

Well it does not quite worked me.

My situation:
I have a working linux install on an old disk I want to replace but keep as data storage / backup. (/dev/sda2)
I have copied whole system over a new disk (/dev/sdb1)

When booting on my old disk, I have a nice boot menu offering to start ubuntu on either the old or the new disk and both are perfectly functionnal.

However when I boot up on my new disk from the bios I have a black screen for few seconds that explains it will be booting from (hd0,0) and after 5 seconds finally boots up normally.

I would like to set the new disk as default boot option, while having the same menu which is very convenient as it allows to boot on old system as back up.

What should it do ? I'm running ubuntu 16.04, perfectly working on both devices.

Comment: is this an EFI or Legacy system? You can clone the entire drive using clonezilla

Comment: It's EFI BIOS. But actually I already copied everything over to the new drive, I don't really want to start again just for a stupid grub menu...

Comment: EFI firmware is not BIOS, grub is not in the MBR. that is why it didn't work. The boot loader is in the EFi partition, and grub references specific sectors. The easiest fix is to clone the drive so you have an exact copy. Copying files doesn't work because they don't end up in the same exact space. partition ID's are different , etc.